# Mocking with Sinon against a service module

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, sinon, sinon-chai

I have got myself to the stage of unit testing, and to be honest, with all the different examples online I have got myself confused.  I have a good understanding of Mocha & Chai, but Sinon is a different story.

So I have what I think is a pretty straight forward setup.  I have a POST route that calls a controller.  This controller is like so (removed some basic validation code)

```
const { createUser } = require('../services/user.service');

const apiResponse = require('../helpers/apiResponse');

const postUser = async (req, res) => {
    const user = {
      account_id: req.body.id,
      status: req.body.status,
      created_at: new Date(),
      updated_at: new Date(),
    };

    const result = await createUser(user);
    return apiResponse.successResponseWithData(res, 'User added.', result.affectedRows);
  } catch (err) {
    return apiResponse.errorResponse(res, err);
  }
};

module.exports = {
  postUser,
};
```

So all it really does is validate, and then creates a user object with the req and pass that to a service class.  This services class does nothing more than pass the data to a database class.

```
const { addUserToDb } = require('../database/user.db');

const createUser = async (user) => {
  try {
    const createdUser = await addUserToDb(user);
    return createdUser;
  } catch (err) {
    throw new Error(err);
  }
};

module.exports = {
  createUser,
};
```

I wont show the database class because what I want to focus on first is the controller, and then I can hopefully do the rest myself.

So from what I understand, I should be testing functions.  If a function makes an external call, I should spy, mock, stub that call?  I should only spy, mock or stub this functions dependencies, if one of the dependencies
has its own dependency (like the service module above having a database call dependency), this should be performed in another test?  Sorry, just a few questions to help me understand.

Anyways, so I have created a user.controller.test.js file.  I have not got far with it, but this is what I have so far

```
const chai = require('chai');
const sinon = require('sinon');

const { expect } = chai;
const faker = require('faker');

const controller = require('../controllers/user.controller');
const service = require('../services/user.service');

const flushPromises = () => new Promise(setImmediate);

describe('user.controller', () => {
  describe('postUser', () => {
    beforeEach(() => {
        //I see a lot of code use a beforeEach, what should I be doing here?
    });

    it('should create a user when account_id and status params are provided', async () => {
      const req = {
        body: { account_id: faker.datatype.uuid(), status: 'true' },
      };

      const stubValue = {
        id: faker.datatype.id(),
        account_id: faker.datatype.uuid(),
        status: 'true',
        created_at: faker.date.past(),
        updated_at: faker.date.past(),
      };
      
    });
  });
});
```

If I am being totally honest I am pretty lost as to what I should be testing here.  From my understanding, I need to mock the service module I think.

Could someone kindly provide some insight as to what I should be doing in this test?

Many thanks

**Update**

Thank you for your detailed response, I have managed to get a spy working which is a step forward.  So I want to do a test on my service module, `createUser` method.

You can see that my `createUser` method takes a user Object as a parameter and passes this to a database module where it is inserted into the database and then the user object returned.

So when testing my service class, I need to mock this call to my database module.

```
const chai = require('chai');
const sinon = require('sinon');

const { expect } = chai;
const faker = require('faker');

const service = require('../services/user.service');
const database = require('../database/user.db');

describe('user.service', () => {
  describe('createUser', () => {
    it('should create a user when user object is provided', async () => {
      const user = {
        id: faker.datatype.string(),
        status: 'true',
        created_at: faker.date.past(),
        updated_at: faker.date.past(),
      };
      const expectedUser = {
        id: user.id,
        status: user.status,
        created_at: user.created_at,
        updated_at: user.updated_at,
      };

      const mockedDatabase = sinon.mock(database);

      mockedDatabase.expects('addUserToDb').once().withArgs(expectedUser);
      await service.createUser(user);

      mockedDatabase.verify();
      mockedDatabase.restore();
    });
  });
});
```

When I test this, I seem to be getting this response, and it still seems to be inserting the record into my database.

```
ExpectationError: Expected addUserToDb({
  id: 'yX7AX\\J&gf',
  status: 'true',
  created_at: 2020-06-03T03:10:23.472Z,
  updated_at: 2020-05-24T14:44:14.749Z
}, '[...]') once (never called)
      at Object.fail (node_modules\sinon\lib\sinon\mock-expectation.js:314:25)
```

Do you have any idea what I am doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

before I try, I would like to suggest to drop the `try/catch` blocks everywhere, I will assume you're using expressJs in your Node application, and for such, take a look at [`express-promise-router`](https://github.com/express-promise-router/express-promise-router) as using that Router (instead the default one) will automatically `catch` anything it was thrown and you just need to focus on the code...

taking your example, you would write:

```js
const { addUserToDb } = require('../database/user.db');

const createUser = async (user) => addUserToDb(user);

module.exports = {
  createUser,
};
```

and

```js
const { createUser } = require('../services/user.service');

const apiResponse = require('../helpers/apiResponse');

const postUser = async (req, res) => {
    const { id: account_id, status } = res.body;
    const result = await createUser({ account_id, status }); // set the date in the fn
    return apiResponse.successResponseWithData(res, 'User added.', result.affectedRows);
};

module.exports = {
  postUser,
};
```

if there's an error and in some place on the route an error is thrown, you will get a nice message back in the response with the error

regarding the code it self, seems a lot cleaner to read - keep in mind that code is for humans, the machine does not even care how you name your variables

---

Now, regarding the tests ... I do tend to split things into 3 parts

- unit tests: *the functions itself, single one, like validation, helpers, etc*
- integration tests: *when you call your API endpoint what should be returned*
- GUI tests (or end-to-end/e2e): *applied when a GUI exists, will skip this for now*

so in your case, the first thing to make sure of is what are you testing... and taking that, start from the small blocks (unit tests) and move up to the blocks that make sure all is glued together (e2e)

[image]

> So all it really does is validate, and then creates a user object with the req and pass that to a service class. This services class does nothing more than pass the data to a database class.

Seems a great way to start, so it "validates" ... let's test our validation, let's pass `null`, `undefined`, `string` when all you want is `int` and so on, until we get a pretty good idea that whatever it passes, we will reply correctly with and without an error

**Note** I tend to use OpenAPI specs, which makes things easier for me as it provides 2 things

- [documentation of the endpoints](https://github.com/Redocly/redoc)
- [validation of the endpoints](https://github.com/cdimascio/express-openapi-validator) with a nice error message to the consumer

and yes, I always test some validation just to make sure it's working as expected, even though I trust the tool 100%

> So from what I understand, I should be testing functions.

well, an application is a group of functions, so all good there

> If a function makes an external call, I should spy, mock, stub that call?

I'll try to explain as best as I can what spies, stubs and mocks in Sinon are, please be gentle

### Spies

they tell us information about functions calls, like, number of times called, arguments, return value, and more - they have two types, anonymous spies or spies that wrap methods in our code

```js
function testMyCallback(callback) { callback(); }

describe('testMyCallback fn', function() {
  it('should call the callback', function() {
    const callbackSpy = sinon.spy(); // anonymous spy - no arguments
    testMyCallback(callbackSpy);
    expect(callbackSpy).to.have.been.calledOnce;
  });
});
```

```js
const user = {
  setNname: function(name) {
    this.name = name;
  }
}

describe('setname fn', function() {
  it('should be called with name', function() {
    const setNameSpy = sinon.spy(user, 'setName'); // wrap method spy
    user.setName('Katie');
    expect(setNameSpy).to.have.been.calledOnce;
    expect(setNameSpy).to.have.been.valledWith('Katie');

    setNameSpy.restore(); // to remove the Spy and prevent future errors
  });
});
```

### Stubs

are power-spies, as they have all the functionality of Spies, but they **replace** the target function, they have methods that can return a specific value or throw a specific exception and a bit more

they are great to be used with your question regarding external calls, as they replace calls (so you can mock the call behavior and never use the original call)

the simplest of the examples is:

```js
function isAdult(age) {
  return age > 21;
}

describe('Sinon Stub Example', () => {
  it('should pass', (done) => {
    const isAdult = sinon.stub().returns('something');
    isAdult(0).should.eql('something');
    isAdult(0).should.not.eql(false);
    done();
  });
});
```

we've STUB'ed our function, and explicitly said it's a "function" that returns a string `something`... and for now on, we will never need to go to the function itself, as we have STUB it, we've replaced the real behavior with our own

another example of using STUBs when calling our API application in our integration tests

```js
describe('when we stub our API call', () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    this.get = sinon.stub(request, 'get'); // stub "request.get" function
  });

  afterEach(() => {
    request.get.restore(); // remove our power-spy
  });

  describe('GET /api/v1/accounts', () => {

    const responseObject = {
      status: 200,
      headers: {
        'content-type': 'application/json'
      }
    };
    const responseBody = {
      status: 'success',
      data: [
        {
          accountId: 1,
          status: 'active'
        },
        {
          accountId: 2,
          status: 'disabled'
        }
      ]
    };

    it('should return all accounts', (done) => {
      // the 3 objects of our callback (err, res, body)
      this.get.yields(null, responseObject, JSON.stringify(responseBody));

      request.get(`${base}/api/v1/movies`, (err, res, body) => {
        expect(res.statusCode).to.be.eql(200);
        expect(res.headers['content-type']).to.contain('application/json');

        body = JSON.parse(body);
        expect(body).to.be.an('array').that.includes(2);
        done();
      });
    });
  });
});
```

you can also stub **axios**, but you will need a new library, either [moxios](https://github.com/axios/moxios), or [proxyquire](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64384423/28004) or more...

### Mocks

are a bit similar to Stubs (our Power-Spies) but they can be used to replace whole objects and alter their behavior, they are mostly used when you need to stub more than one function from a single object - if all you need is to replace a single function, a stub is easier to use

Mocks can make things oversimplify and you could break your application without even knowing, so be aware...

a normally use is, for example

```js
function setupNewAccount(info, callback) {
  const account = {
    account_id: info.id,
    status: info.status,
    created_at: new Date(),
    updated_at: new Date()
  };
  try { Database.save(account, callback); }
  catch (err) { callback(err); }
}

describe('setupNewAccount', function() {
  it('', function() {
    const account = { account_id: 1, status: 'active' };
    const expectedAccount = {
       account_id: account.id, status: account.status
    };
    const database = sinon.mock(Database);

    database.expectes('save').once().withArgs(expectedAccount);

    setupNewAccount(account, function() {});

    database.verify();
    database.restore();
  });
});
```

something that we will keep forgetting is the `.restore()` part, and for that, there's a package (one more...) called [`sinon-test`](https://github.com/sinonjs/sinon-test) that will auto cleanup at the end of a test

---

I just hope it helped you with some of your questions and it's a bit clearer now

BTW, for stubbing HTTP requests, I use [`nock`](https://github.com/nock/nock) as I think it's much easier to read and use than Sinon, especially for anyone that is reading code for the first time and has no experience in either Sinon or Nock...

Comment: Thank you for your detailed response, I am still having a few issues and not too sure why.  I have left an update to my post, do you have an idea of why this may be happening?  Thanks

Comment: in your service, try to do `db.addUserToDb(user);` so, without destructuring the `addUserToDb` but with `const db = require('../database/user.db');` - [here's why](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52591287/28004)

Comment: Thank you so much.  Been trying to figure this out for a long time, wow that was a simple fix!  I have marked your answer as correct, and will award the bounty when it lets me in 2 hours :-) Many thanks for your detailed explanation.

Comment: was never about points, it was only for helping out a fellow Stackoverflow member  and review what I knew about Sinon, something I stopped using a long time ago... I just hope you have learned a bit more after this, it was fun to answer 