# Stub axios api call

Tags: javascript, node.js, axios, sinon

I have a request where I am using Axios API to make external request.

Example.

```
axios({
  method: 'get',
  url: 'xxxxx',
  responseType: 'json'
})
 .then((data) => data)
 .catch((err) => err)
```

How we can stub API response.
I have tried stubbing methods `request`, `options`.

How can I stub above API call.

```
sandbox.stub(externalRequest.Axios.prototype, 'init').resolves(resp);
```

Thank you.

Comment: What do you mean "stub"? `.then((data) => data)` does exactly nothing. It takes `data` as input and... returns `data` as output.

Comment: I want to stub that response. Instead of data I want to send my own response. So that test case will not make any external request.

Comment: Aaaah I get it. Unfortunately I don't know how to do that :/

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I mock an async function that makes network request using axios?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64374809/how-do-i-mock-an-async-function-that-makes-network-request-using-axios)

Answer (score 1):

If you need to stub `axios` for your tests, I recommend you to check out [axios-mock-adapter](https://github.com/ctimmerm/axios-mock-adapter) which allows you to mock responses with an easy API.

```js
var axios = require("axios");
var MockAdapter = require("axios-mock-adapter");

// This sets the mock adapter on the default instance
var mock = new MockAdapter(axios);

// Mock any GET request to /users
// arguments for reply are (status, data, headers)
mock.onGet("/users").reply(200, {
  users: [{ id: 1, name: "John Smith" }],
});
```

Comment: But request can be get or post. How to dynamically stub any request. I think `.onGet` only stubs for get request?

Comment: `onAny` is there. Thanks